# Watts-Strogatz algorithm for creating small world networks: Why a ring lattice?

Tags: algorithm, neural-network, social-networking, graph-theory

I am curious to know why the Watts-Strogatz random graph generation model uses a ring 
lattice in its algorithm.

I am creating a spatially embedded network, where nodes are randomly placed on a grid. Each
node will connect to its k-nearest neighbors. Then, at random with probability p, connections 
are rewired.

In principle, this sounds exactly the same as the Watts-Strogatz algorithm, but nodes are 
not neatly organised in a lattice. In terms of the logical topology, are there any significant
differences?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question (why using a ring): to my opinion, they used a ring lattice because it's the simplest form of lattice, and they didn't need to use a more complex form to illustrate their point. By using the ring as a starting point and by applying their rewiring process, they showed they could obtain the desired topological properties.

For your second question (regarding your own method), I think the effect depends on the spatial distribution of the nodes. Also, what is the exact rule you use to create a link between two nodes? Do both nodes need to be among the k-nearest neighbors of one another? (in which case the maximal degree is k), or do you apply only a unilateral condition? (and then, the degree can be much larger than k depending on the spatial distribution).